# If $ne^{-b_n x} \to 0$ for $x>1$ and $ne^{-b_n x} \to \infty$ for $x<1$, does $ne^{-b_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $b_n>0$ with $b_n \to \infty$. If $ne^{-b_n x} \to 0$ for any $x>1$ and $ne^{-b_n x} \to \infty$ for any $x<1$, does $ne^{-b_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$?.

I know for example that if $b_n = \ln n$,  $ne^{-b_n x} \to 0$ for any $x>1$ and $ne^{-b_n x} \to \infty$ for any $x<1$ with $ne^{-b_n} =1$. However, I'm not sure if there might be $b_n$ such that $ne^{-b_n x} \to 0$ for any $x>1$ and $ne^{-b_n x} \to \infty$ but not $ne^{-b_n} \to 1$.

For example, $b_n = \ln \ln x$ doesn't satisfy the condition  $ne^{-b_n x} \to 0$ for any $x>1$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take $b_n= (1+\epsilon_n)\ln n$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\epsilon_n=0$. If $x>1$, $\ln n -b_n x< -\frac {x-1}2 \ln n$ for $n$ large enough, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n e^{-b_n x}=0$. If $x<1$, , $\ln n -b_n x>  \frac {1-x}2 \ln n$ for $n$ large enough, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n e^{-b_n x}=+\infty$. We cannnot say anything on the behavior of $ne^{-b_n}= e^{-\epsilon_n \ln n}$. (For  instance, take $\epsilon_n =k(\ln n)^{-\gamma}$ with $k$ and $\gamma$ positive constants; then $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n e^{-b_n}=l$ with $l=+\infty$ if $\gamma<1$, $l=1$ if $\gamma>1$, $l=e^{-k}$ if $\gamma=1$; another example is $b_n=(-1)^n  +\ln n$, for which $n e^{-b_n}$ has no limit.

Answer (score 0):

Letting $c_n=b_n-\ln n$ and $a=1-\frac1x,$ your question is equivalent to: if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(c_n+a\ln n)=\begin{cases}+\infty&\text{if }a>0\\-\infty&\text{if }a<0,\end{cases}$$
i.e.

> if (as $n\to\infty$) $$\forall \lambda\in\Bbb R\quad\ln n+\lambda c_n\to+\infty,$$
> do we necessarily have$$c_n\to0?$$

The answer is obviously "no": many sequences $(c_n)$ are [$o(\ln n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) without converging to $0.$ They can even have no limit at all.